# Python - Check if linux partition is read-only or read-write?

Tags: python, linux

I have a python application running on a beaglebone. How do I (in Python) check if the "/mnt" partition is mounted as read-only or read-write?

Comment: Hey Boris, this looks like an interesting question, but maybe you should read the SO FAQ and than modify it to resemble the style we like to see on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'was able to do this:     out = os.popen('mount | grep /mnt').read() and then parse the output string " /dev/mmcblk0p4 on /mnt type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)" but feel like there should be a better way.

Comment: beaglebone running python... good luck

Comment: @Borisw37: Yes, you don't need to call an external command (and BTW `popen` is superseded by `subprocess` for that sort of thing). You can use `os.access(dirname, os.W_OK)`, as I mentioned in my comment to andrekeller.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: The answer makes the assumption that you plan to write to /mnt.

I would just try to write to it and catch OSError exception to handle the read-only case.

Comment: Why the downvote? I believe this is a valid approach as it avoids race-conditions with change states between check and actual writing.

Comment: Agreed. You _could_ use `os.access(dirname, os.W_OK)`, but as the docs say: `Note: Using access() to check if a user is authorized to e.g. open a file before actually doing so using open() creates a security hole, because the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening the file to manipulate it.` Also, `Note: I/O operations may fail even when access() indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model.`

Comment: @andrekeller, because checking something by altering its state is a bad idea. `def exists(path): os.remove(path) ; print 'File existsed'` is classic joke.

Comment: @myaut: well depends what you actually want to achieve. If the program depends on writing to /mnt what I assumed, then I think its better to try and catch the exception than to check first if its writable.

Comment: @myaut: Fair point, but why do you  _need_ to know if a partition is writeable unless you do, in fact, intend to write to it? [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) is the Python Way. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring, ah that seems reasonable. But OP didn't mention that he is writing something on that partition ;)

Comment: I'm trying to prevent possible SD card corruption. The idea is that (through a cherry-py webserver) user can see the status of the partition and be able to manually set it to ro/rw before uploading files to it using WinSCP. The user needs to know if the partition is RO or RW to serve as a warning.

Comment: in that case Jamie Cockburn has the answer

Comment: @Borisw37: Ah. In that case you should edit that information into your question.

Answer (score 7):

Solution is pretty much trivial, with only 1 syscall (statvfs).

```
stat = os.statvfs('/mnt')

# Python < 3.2
ST_RDONLY = 1
readonly = bool(stat.f_flag & ST_RDONLY)

# Python >= 3.2
readonly = bool(stat.f_flag & os.ST_RDONLY)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you:

```
def isMountReadonly(mnt):
    with open('/proc/mounts') as f:
        for line in f:
            device, mount_point, filesystem, flags, __, __ = line.split()
            flags = flags.split(',')
            if mount_point == mnt:
                return 'ro' in flags
        raise ValueError('mount "%s" doesn\'t exist' % mnt)

print "read only: %s" % isMountReadonly('/mnt')
```

Output:

```
read only: False
```